# urllib2 does not change IP with proxy

Tags: python, proxy, ip, urllib2, urllib

i've created a little code to test if my IP is changed when I connect to a proxy server. But the IP does not change. What is my problem?

```
from helpers import GetProxyList
import urllib2

proxyList = GetProxyList()
my_ip = urllib2.urlopen('http://icanhazip.com/').read()
print(my_ip)

for proxy in proxyList:
    #proxyObj = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https':'https://'+proxy+'/'})
    proxy_url = 'http://'+proxy+'/'
    proxy_url_https = 'https://'+proxy+'/'
    #proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': proxy_url, 'https':proxy_url_https})
    proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https': proxy_url_https})

    opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler, urllib2.HTTPHandler)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    new_ip = urllib2.urlopen('http://icanhazip.com/').read()
    print(new_ip)
```

I have tried it in various ways, as you can see in the comments. 
Even with the urllib, but it doesn't work.

The GetProxyList() function returns a list of proxy from http://www.workingproxies.org/. May be you can test it with the first 2 entities.

I thank you in advance for helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this line:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler, urllib2.HTTPHandler)
```

You should change it to this:

```
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': proxy_url})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
```

If you still have problems with a route being not found, you might want to check your DNS settings.
See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.build_opener) for more information on the build_opener.
And [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44673/no-route-to-host-proxy-issue) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.6/+bug/94130) for infos about how to fix a route not being found.

Comment: Doesn't work. But I didn't continue my searching for a solution. I have a workaround with `torify` my real application.